# Error generating INNOSetup installer with ocra and sqlite

Tags: ruby, sqlite, inno-setup, ocra

I am trying to package a ruby + qtruby + sqlite3 application with ocra into a windows installer.

Everithing goes well, until I add the code that connects to the database.

Here is the snippet:

```
require 'Qt4'
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'

dbconfig = YAML::load(File.open('src/config/database.yml'))['development']
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
:adapter => dbconfig['adapter'],
:database => dbconfig['database']
)

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Category.find(:all)

exit if Object.const_defined?(:Ocra)
...
```

This code runs and ocra is able to create the single executable file, but if I try to create a setup file this is the error I get:

```
=== Running InnoSetup compiler ISCC                                                                                       
Error in D:\Workspaces\Ruby\TestGui\ocratemp.iss: Impossibile accedere al file. Il file Þ utilizzato da un altro processo.
Compile aborted.                                                                                                          
ERROR: InnoSetup installer creation failed: ISCC failed to run. Is the InnoSetup directory in your PATH?                  
rake aborted!
```

The error is in Italian, sorry, but it translates to "**Cannot access the file. The file is currently used by another process**"

This is the command used to generate the installer:

```
ocra --chdir-first --no-lzma --no-autoload --innosetup testGui.iss gui.rb src/db/development.db src/config/database.yml
```

If I comment away the block of code that connects to sqlite, the installer is created correctly and I can use on a test machine correctly.
If I move the *exit if...* block before connecting to sqlite the resulting executable/installer lacks the sqlite libraries and in the target machine I can not execute it.

I think the error is related to the connection to sqlite not being closed, but perhaps I am missing something else.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the command you're using to run ocra, as well?

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry. I edited the post

Comment: Have you tried ProcessMonitor (or a similar program) to find out which file it is complaining about? Does it work if you omit src/db/development.db from the ocra command line?

Comment: if I omit the DB file, it works without issues. I tried ProcessMonitor but I saw nothing about development.db or ocratemp.iss

Comment: Have you tried explicitly releasing / closing the connection to SQLite before calling #exit ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but i just had this same error. As soon as I shut off the Anti-Virus software I had running everything worked perfectly. My install file was created and functioned as it should.